# references for abstract harmonic analysis

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis

I am currently studying a basic course in abstract harmonic analysis. I do have a good background in abstract algebra and functional analysis but I have not done a course in Fourier analysis. Is it compulsory to have a background of Fourier analysis to grasp the concepts of abstract harmonic analysis or is  a good background in abstract algebra and functional analysis sufficient to study harmonic analysis?

if possible,please mention some texts which do not consider much background of Fourier analysis for beginners in a basic abstract harmonic analysis course and are easier to understand....

thanks a lot...

Comment: this is like asking "is it possible to do Lebesgue measure in general without doing Lebesgue measure in Euclidean space?" the answer is yes, but many people much prefer to see the concrete case first. in any case, there are standard references here: Loomis, Folland. for newer books, look at Deitmar's.